# How to say what I want to say?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

> 1. I put that there so she see it.
> 2. I put that in her ---- .

I mean 2 to say the same as 1. So how to complete 2? Any of the blow, or something else?

I put that in her eyesight.

I put that in her eyesight direction.
...

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "field of vision."  One can also say, "I put it where she can see it."

Comment: @aparente001 That is a good suggestion. I think it would be good to suggest it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for "field of vision." One can also say, "I put it where she can see it."

Comment: Yeah, that and "visual field" are good suggestions.

Comment: Note that "visual field" sounds more technical.  I wouldn't use it in casual conversation.